# <br> tag gets inserted instead of '\r\n'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm up making a text editor with mic and typing suupport. I've using jQuery with it(not learnerd it fully thouugh) but there seems to be a bug. I have set up a event listener that will listen for the enter key and will add '\r\n' but instead it gets `<br>` added in the `<p>` tags. And when I type in, the `<br>` gets disappered and the typed text fills in. Please try to understand, don't call me a noob though I'm still 15.

I've also set up a save option for which I'm struggling so much for the new line but it ain't coming in.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#download').click(function() {
    $('p').find('br').before(document.createTextNode('\n')).remove();
    $('p').contents().unwrap().wrapAll('<p>');
    $('p').attr("id", "p");
    downloadInnerHtml('notes.txt', 'p', 'txt');
  });
});
```

JS

```
let p = document.createElement('p');
const notes = document.querySelector('#notes');
p.setAttribute('id', 'p');
notes.appendChild(p);
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');
recognition.addEventListener('result', e => {
  const transcript = Array.from(e.results)
    .map(result => result[0])
    .map(result => result.transcript)
    .join('')

  p.textContent = transcript;
  if (e.results[0].isFinal) {
    p = document.createElement('p');
    p.setAttribute('id', 'p');
    notes.appendChild(p);
  }
  console.log(transcript);
});
notes.addEventListener('beforeinput', function() {
  document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');
});
notes.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    document.getElementById('p').append('\n');
    document.getElementById('p').append('\n');
  }
});
recognition.addEventListener('end', recognition.start);
recognition.start();

function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elTag, mimeType) {
  var elHtml = document.getElementById(elTag).innerHTML;
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
  link.click();
}
```

I expected a newline but on save button the function should also include the newline character but that itself is nothappening. Like,

Expected output:-

```
I am someone.

Foo bar.
```

Actual output:-

```
I am someone.Foo bar.
```

Comment: Except in `<pre>` elements or elements with `white-space: pre` (or similar) style, newlines are treated like spaces and collapsed. You should use `<br>` to create a line break in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML any and all (with exception of non-breaking) whitespace is collapsed into a single space. For example:

```
<span>Hello<span>\n
<span>World<span>
```

I have included `\n` to highlight the explicit newline. However, the above will render as:

> Hello World

This is expected HTML behaviour, so you will find that what other editors do is to transparently convert between newlines and `<br>` for storage vs display, and you'll need to do the same.

---

Edit:

You're using a `<div>` as the base for your editor. Maybe you should use `<textarea>` instead, which is more purpose-made for the stated goal of being an editor.
Also, try [this W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_textarea_get) for clearly seeing how what you generate as text will be shown when placed verbatim in HTML (click "Try it" then add a `<br/>` somewhere and click "Try it" again).

Comment: Thats okay, but how do i add the '\n' outside the tags? its gonna be a hard time doin' that. Help me if you couuld.

Comment: Is the problem something that you can condense into a jsFiddle to demonstrate what is happening? I'm not entirely sure where or when you're looking to produce the extra lines.

Comment: Check this obnoxiousnerd.github.io/escot

Comment: Or the repo github.com/obnoxiousnerd/escot

Comment: How do I operate it? I just see a "save note" button.

Comment: when site loads, your mic will start, then talk in a word and the div will show up(yet another bug). Just keep an eye on the console. Typing in it will get you an idea what i've got to say

Comment: https://github.com/obnoxiousnerd/css-and-js/blob/master/issue.mp4?raw=true

Comment: `$('p').find('br').before(document.createTextNode('\n')).remove();`
This line replaces all your `<br>`s with a newline. It works. But like I said, you need a `<br>` to visually have a newline showing when you're doing this in HTML. Maybe I'm still not understanding your additional requirement? Have you considered using `textarea` instead of `div`? If I do, a save dialog actually pops up when hitting 'save note'. `textarea` is made for entering text and might save you battling with DOM manipulation instead of focusing on your mic input etc.

Comment: What can i do this line so that it'll keep the newlines intact?   ```javscript $('p').contents().unwrap().wrapAll('<p>');```

Comment: could you help me by collabing on my repo. It's kinda tough